# gamma function question relating to normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to show that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$. A hint I've been given is to use a change of variable and then relate it to normal distribution density. However, I'm really confused as to how I would go about it this way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using the integral form of the gamma function?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^ \infty e^{-t} \frac{ dt}{\sqrt{t}}
$$

Now with $du = \frac{ dt}{\sqrt{t}}$, you find that
$$
u = 2\sqrt{t} \implies t = u^ 2/4
$$
Let $\sigma^2 = 2$.
$$
\Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^ \infty e^{-u^2/2\sigma^2} du = \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^ 2}/2 = \sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: Sorry I'm confused as to why you let $\sigma^2 = 2$ and how you got $e^{-u^2/2\sigma^2}$

Comment: $e^ {-t} dt/\sqrt{t} = e^ {-u^ 2/4} du$. I chose to note $\sigma^ 2 = 2$ to fit with probability notations.

Comment: I'm still confused about $\sigma^ 2 = 2$ - how does this fit with probability notations???

Comment: because the pdf of the normal distribution is $e^ {-t^ 2/2\sigma^ 2} 1/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^ 2}$

Answer (score 0):

Proof 1: using the Reflection Formula

$$\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)^2=\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac12\right)=\frac\pi{\sin\frac\pi2}=\pi\implies\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$$

Proof 2: With Normal Dist. and stuff:

$$\Gamma(t):=\int\limits_0^\infty x^{1-t}e^{-x}dx\stackrel{x=u^2}=2\int\limits_0^\infty u^{2t-1}e^{-u^2}du\implies$$

$$\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=2\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt\pi$$

Comment: Both your proofs make sense, but I'm not sure how you used the normal distribution in the second proof.

Comment: Well, since you asked a proof using that I assumed you know the value of that improper integral: the gaussian normalizing constant of the normal distribution...